# How to Search in starting letters in text box?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a Input with list which it's searching in my data. everything is fine but i want to make it work like below:

when i search Hello, results are like this:

`Examples: Hello there, Code with Hello, CodeWithHelloThere.`

now last one is my problem, which i want my code to search in first letters not in middle of letters, i'm doing this for my homework so i'm not experienced at this.

```
<div class="col-md-3">

     <div class="item form-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="name">معرفین<span class="required">*</span>
               </label>
               <select v-model="reagents" onchange="this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))" class="form-control reagent_selector"  name="reagents[]" multiple="multiple" id="">
                    @foreach ($reagents as $item)
                        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                     @endforeach
               </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Laravel Controller :

```
public function p_show()
{
    $reagents=Reagent::all()->sortBy("name");
    return view('panel.report.p_report',compact(['reagents']));
}
```

Output is like this :

[Image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUCRK.png)

Update 1: i'm going to make things clear, i'm using `vue.js` which there's not anything special in it, not any computed or watch or method to do my search. i'm getting data from controller and putting it in `reagents:'';`. and using reagents in top v-model, which it's a text-box and when u enter something it will show a list and the list is base on characters I've entered and received from data.

Update 2: Full codes

[Full Codes for this file](https://github.com/King-of-the-Past/laravel-test-app/blob/master/p_report_blade.php)

Comment: So... where is the code that performs the actual search / matching?

Comment: @TobiasF.hello mate, i'm using laravel to get data, which is top code. and using vue.js to get data, and put it in listbox & text box.

Comment: Where are you filtering the string "Hello"?  Post the code, please.

Comment: @CarlosAfonso sir i'm using vue.js, check image output i've added in below, that's the out put of top code, there's a text box, and when u type, it will show results base on received data with ajax. there's not anything special in vue.js part, like all other app in data there's a reagents section which i put my data in it, and use it in top, as u can see `@reagents as $item.` in top

Comment: You are filtering the reagents in VueJs then? Can you post the Vue method that works that out?

Comment: @CarlosAfonso i've explained at top i'm not filtering anything. in vue,js there's only data:{reagents:null}' that's all. it's simple  i don't get how it's not clear, for the value and name at top[in text-box & result List], i'm using recieved data from blade, which i'll put that data in reagents in vue. there's also pictures at top.

Comment: You said you're searching Hello and you're getting `CodeWithHelloThere` in your results... I'd like to know where this search with what you type is happening. Are you using any Vue plugin for `select` like `Vue-multiselect`, for example? I honestly can't see how your search is happening so out-of-the-box like that.

Comment: @CarlosAfonso i've added full code. at bottom, please check, the output should be like the image i've added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filtering is being processed by `Select2`. You can set this function I've borrowed from the [official documentation](https://select2.org/searching) and modified in order to achieve your goal.

```
$('.reagent_selector').select2({
    width: '100%',
    matcher: function(params, data) {
        if(params.term.trim() === '')
            return data;

        if(typeof data.text === 'undefined')
            return null;

        if(data.text.toLowerCase().match('\\b' + params.term.toLowerCase()))
            return data;

        return null;
    }
});
```

I changed the search function to match only the options that contain at least one **word** starting with the input text.

The `\\b` up there is a regex anchor used to match "word boundary". In this case, I'm forcing the input text to be at the beginning of a word, not in the middle.

Comment: well, i've tried with this, but i've got no result. when i remove '\\b', it will give me the same result without limited, still same. so i guess this is kinda wrong.

Comment: any suggestion my friend?

Comment: I've just figured out `\b` works only under a certain range of characters. You must change `\\b` with the regex range according to your language. Arabic, for example, would be `[^\u0621-\u064A]`. Also, you should try to append it either to the left or to the right of the input text depending on the direction of the text you're working.

Comment: well, i'll try. my text direction is RTL.